# Angular 2 PrimeNG build DataTable from multidimensional array

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

The server API returns data in the following form:

```js
export interface Response {
  cols: string[];
  rows: string[][];
}
```

`cols` array contains header names, while the each element of `rows` is an array containing some values, so the example of the response looks like this: 
[image: server response example]

I need to build the PrimeNG DataTable using received data, but in the documentation there is no such example. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you fetched data from your backend like that :

```
this.backendData = {
    cols:['name', 'Income last year'],
    rows:[['Lionbridge', 150250], ['Locatech', 1085]]
}
```

First, you have to create PrimeNG columns dynamically from these backend data :

```
this.cols = [];
var i, row, obj;
for(i=0;i<this.backendData.cols.length;i++) {
    this.cols.push(this.constructColumn(this.backendData.cols[i]));
}
```

Then, you have to fill the data for the PrimeNG datatable like that (by iterating on each row of backend rows data) :

```
this.data = [];
for(row=0;row<this.backendData.rows.length;row++) {
    obj = {};
    for(i=0;i<this.backendData.cols.length;i++) {
        obj[this.backendData.cols[i]] = this.backendData.rows[row][i];
    }
    this.data.push(obj);
}
```

Finally, just associate that data to the view :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data">
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Here is a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wyzIoGull9NPKGbFNj5w?p=preview)

Is that ok for you ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you a lot!